# Sending instance of JavaScript class over AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an instance of a JavaScript class [server -> client]

but when the data makes it to the client it loses all reference to its constructor.


Workable solutions(?)

- have the class reference persist across the transfer

- set the returned object to an instance of its previous class

Object immediately before being sent to client:

```
[ { name: 'P',
graph: 
 Graph {
   _isDirected: true,
   _isMultigraph: true,
   // more properties
 }
} ]
```

Object received from AJAX call:
[image: object on client (not member of Graph class anymore)]

Comment: look into JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

Comment: I've tried coercing the object to JSON, but the class information is still lost